# How "store" REST archetype isn't creating a new resource and a new URI?

Tags: rest, api-design

REST API design indicates there are four resources archetypes: document, collection, store and controller.

Store do not create new resources; therefore a store never generates new URIs.

An example:

```
PUT /users/12245/favorites/boston-celtics
```

A user added Boston Celtics to his favorites list.

But how that isn't creating a new resource ? and how it isnt generating a new URI?

Comment: I think it is worth to comment that "archetypes" are just a terminology created on the book from Mark Massé, Rest API Design Rulebook

Comment: There is no connection between REST and the terms you describe above except in one rather underwhelming book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A store does not create a resource on its own. The user of the store creates endpoints / URIs.

The contrast is between a Collection and a Store

Collection
A collection resource is a server-managed directory of resources. Clients may propose new resources to be added to a collection. However, it is up to the collection to choose to create a new resource, or not. A collection resource chooses what it wants to contain and also decides the URIs of each contained resource.

Store
A store is a client-managed resource repository. A store resource lets an API client: put resources in, get them back out, and decide when to delete them.

Comment: The linked resource no longer exists.

Comment: This answer gives no more information than what is already in the doc. If you could give an example of client manager resource and server managed that would have helped.